# Doctrine substring field with alias in where clause

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following query:

```
$query = $qb->select($qb->expr()->substring("p.website",1,5).'AS country)
        ->from("AppBundle\Entity\Image" ,"p")
        ->where("p.aktuellste = 1")
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('country',':country'))
        ->setParameter(':country','de')
        ->orderBy('country','DESC')
        ->getQuery();
```

E.g. I would like to select all lines where `substring(1,2)` of website is `de`. But `country` is an unknown column for Doctrine in the `WHERE` clause. The following exception is thrown:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sclr_0' in
>   'where clause

The funny thing is that Doctrine knows the `country` column in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Not sure if that helps, but use the prefix p in all where expressions. And MySQL knows the column "country" in the order clause, because the "temporary" table (after the select execution) has the field country. (Please correct me, if thats a wrong understanding!!)

Comment: Hey thank you but i already tried this one. The problem is that doctrine expects the "country" field in my "Image" class.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to search on an aliased column, you need to use `HAVING`, because that is on a calculated field.  Putting it in your `WHERE` clause is assuming that your `Image` entity has a member named `country` in it, which it does not.

```
$query = $qb
    ->select($qb->expr()->substring('p.website', 1, 5).'AS country')
    ->from('AppBundle\Entity\Image', 'p')
    ->andWhere('p.aktuellste = 1')
    ->andHaving($qb->expr()->in('country', ':country'))
    ->setParameter(':country', 'de')
    ->orderBy('country', 'DESC')
    ->getQuery()
;
```

See [MySQL Handling of Group By](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) for more information:

> The MySQL extension permits the use of an alias in the HAVING clause
>   for the aggregated column

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors in your query, but not sure this fixes your problem.
Please try this:

```
$query = $qb->select($qb->expr()->substring("p.website",1,5).'AS country')
    ->from("AppBundle\Entity\Image" ,"p")
    ->where("p.aktuellste = 1")
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('country=:country'))
    ->setParameter('country','de')
    ->orderBy('country','DESC')
    ->getQuery();
```

Comment: thanks but i dont think that i got syntax error because ur query fails because of missing parameter in "IN expression" 
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('country=:country'))